# Equilibrium point of a linear system of DE's

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the following linear system:
$$\dot{x} = \sigma - kx$$
$$\dot{y} = -kx+k_1(y_m-y)$$

With $k,k_1,\sigma,y_m\in \mathbb{R}^+$. (That is, all strictly positive constants.)

My textbook claims that these can be simplified into one linear equation, but I did not see how so I decided to attempt to solve the equilibria directly.

Solving for $x$ first:
$$0 = \sigma - kx \implies x = \sigma/k$$

And then substituting and solving for $y$:
$$0 = -k(\sigma/k)+k_1(y_m-y)$$
$$0 = -\sigma+k_1y_m-k_1y$$
$$k_1y=-\sigma+k_1y_m$$
$$y = -\sigma/k_1 + y_m$$

Did I do this correctly? Is the equilibrium of the system at 
$$x = \sigma/k, \ y = \sigma/k_1+y_m?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any problem with our OP jeanquilt's solution for the equilibrium values of $x$ and $y$:

$x = -\dfrac{\sigma}{k}, \tag 1$

$y = -\dfrac{\sigma}{k_1} + y_m. \tag 2$

Meanwhile, from

$\dot y = -kx + k_1(y_m - y), \tag 3$

we have

$\ddot y = -k \dot x -k_1 \dot y; \tag 4$

then we may use

$\dot x = \sigma -kx \tag 5$

to obtain

$\ddot y = -k\sigma + k^2x -k_1 \dot y; \tag 6$

from (3) we have

$x = \dfrac{1}{k}(-\dot y + k_1(y_m - y)); \tag 7$

if we substitute this back into (6) we find

$\ddot y = -k\sigma + k(-\dot y + k_1(y_m - y)) - k_1\dot y = -k\sigma - (k + k_1)\dot y - kk_1y + kk_1y_m, \tag 8$

or

$\ddot y + (k + k_1)\dot y +kk_1y + (k\sigma - kk_1y_m) = 0, \tag 9$

an equation in only $y$; the equation for $x$ is already in single-variable form.

Comment: Nice--I thought since the system is partially decoupled they should be solvable but this makes the system completely decoupled. Thank you!

Comment: @jeanquilt:  Yes, one could also solve for $x(t)$ directly from (5) and then substitute the result into (3) to obtain a simple system solvable for $y(t)$.